# Cache Razor view excluding the _Layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to cache the content of your view excluding the shared _Layout i have the output cache attribute set on my controller for an  Action of type ViewResult and it caches content which is defined on the _Layout also. This means it cache's things like username,etc which may not be valid if i am not logged in but previously visited the page when logged in.

Would changing the action to a PartialViewResult resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

In MCV the cache is based in controller not on View so you cannot do it with view or PartialViewResult but you can use `@Html.Action` to cache partially in this case you have to define a new action for all Partial items and call the the view from the result of that action.

Finally don t forget `Layout = null;` code in the partial view you call it from action as it cause caching error and there is also same Data annotation for this issue but forgot it I think it was just `[PartialAction]` not sure to be honest.